# Catch "Video already in playlist." error in Youtube API (Python)

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, http-error

I'm using the `youtube.playlistItems().insert` [function](http://youtube.playlistItems().insert) in a Python script. I know that some videos are already in the targeted playlist, which leads to an error

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 409 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Video already in playlist.">
```

How can I catch this error and just skip the video in question? I searched the [insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) help doc and the [errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) doc but could not find the appropriate attribute of my request to access (`.error` and `.httperror` did not work).

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to use a try and except block?

Comment: @BrendenPrice Indeed, I was looking for the variable to enter in the `except`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just catch the exception and continue like so:

```py
try:
    youtube.playlistItems().insert()
except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
    pass
```

I took a look at the API, and think it's worth considering the quota cost of `insert()`. The `insert()` method costs 50 and the `list()` method costs 1. Depending on the volume of requests, it may be wise to check the list of existing playlist items before attempting to insert a duplicate.

```py
current_items = youtube.playlistItems().list()
if item_to_insert not in current_items:
    youtube.playlistItems().insert(item_to_insert)
```

The value of this strategy depends entirely on the proportion of duplicates and your willingness to pay the API cost. Also, I'm not suggesting you call `list()` for each insertion, it would be better to call `list()` once and then batch the inserts, this is just a quick example.

Comment: I resolved my related issue by wrapping the function that calls the API in a `try` block as shown.